# How to close one fancybox, but not closing current opened?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have form inside my fancybox, and in form i have link to terms agreement, so when i click to read term, my window with form automatically closed, and when i close term - i can't return to my form. How can i save previous window and opend another ? 
Here's code to call window with form:

```
$.fancybox({
        href: '#lead_window',
        fitToView: false, // allows extend fancybox outside viewport 
        autoCenter: false, // allows scroll fancybox along the body
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                locked: true // allows scrolling outside fancybox
            }
        },
        afterShow: function() {
            if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
                $('#lead_window input:first').focus();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you open the "terms" in a new window/tab? http://jsfiddle.net/u7gax3u3/

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade to v3. One of the key features of fancyBox 3 is to display multiple instances at once. See, for example, Ajax demo at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/